# How to Display PrimeVue Dynamic DataTable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

I've been trying to make a Dynamic DataTable appear by referring to [Prime Vue DataTable Documention](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/#/datatable/dynamiccolumns) using the Composition API. I have no issues with the Basic DataTable using both Compositon and Options API and it seems that whenever I try to make the DataTable dynamic using `v-for`the DataTable will not appear.

Also, from my understanding that PrimeVue DataTable does not have any restrictions on how the data is provided in the [DataTable Getting Started Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/#/datatable).

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

**Here is code in DynamicTable.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <DataTable :value="cars">
      <Column
        v-for="col of columns"
        :field="col.field"
        :header="col.header"
        :key="col.field"
      ></Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      cars.value = [
        { brand: "Volkswagen", year: 2012, color: "Orange", vin: "dsad231ff" },
        { brand: "Audi", year: 2011, color: "Black", vin: "gwregre345" },
        { brand: "Renault", year: 2005, color: "Gray", vin: "h354htr" },
      ];
    });

    const columns = ref([
      { field: "vin", header: "VIN" },
      { field: "year", header: "Year" },
      { field: "color", header: "Color" },
      { field: "brand", header: "Brand" },
    ]);

    const cars = ref([]);

    return { columns, cars };
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: I can't see any wrong here. This code snipped works perfectly.